# Django tries to import nonexistent class

Tags: django, caching, django-templates, gunicorn

I was working in one branch, where I have added few models and used them in inclusion tags.
After switching to another branch (which does not contain these models), I am not able to load any page -  I get these:

```
Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'myapp.templatetags.shopcart_pack_counters': cannot import name ShopCart
```

in render() function.
I have tried to clear caches, but that does not help. If I clone the project again and switch to the second branch, everything works fine (unless I do not switch the first one and back again). What can I do to fix that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. 
Did you merge the branches?

Comment: You have to compare both branches and see what the differences are. We cannot guess what content is in each branch, for what we know this could be an entirely different project. Could you provide more info ?

Comment: I have not merged. As I have said, if I clone project in another folder, its working ok. The error happens if I switch first branch to the second one.

Comment: Btw, I can not find any "ShopCart" mentions in the project, when Im in the second branch as well as the shopcart_pack_counters tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not found a good solution, I have discovered the issue happening during the import of myapp.templatetags module. Solved by creating empty .py files for nonexistent tags, causing the exceptions. After they are compiled, everything works well.
This happened to me in Django 1.11.25 and python 2.7.17.